# Mirroring static websites to Google App Engine using a Mercurial repository

Tags: google-app-engine, mercurial, github, mirror, bitbucket

Hi there everybody. I would like to know if something like [Drydrop](http://drydrop.binaryage.com/), but using a Mercurial repository instead of a Git one, exists.

(I know that I could just mirror my original repository to Github or some other Git hosting service, I only wanted to be sure there was not a more direct alternative).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drydrop simply relies on post-commit hooks and reading the raw files from the web interface - to the best of my knowledge, very little in it is Git specific. It should be fairly straightforward to modify it for any type of repository, presuming it supports post-commit hooks.

Comment: and mercurial does post-commit hooks just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your fine information. I didn't studied drydrop behaviour in detail (in fact, I hadn't ever cared to bookmark its URL the first time I heard of it), but as it works as you said, such a modification should be feasible.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?